# Apache not serving files from STATIC_ROOT but static directory Django

Tags: django, apache

**EDIT** Question Answered. Was updating the wrong config file.

I am trying to get Apache(2.4.7 (Ubuntu)) to serve files from `staticfiles` directory as my `STATIC_ROOT`. However on my machine using apache it seems to serve files from the `static` directory instead.

These are my settings related to static files in `settings.py`

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/myproject/staticfiles/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
  # other finders..
  'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

These are settings related to static files in apache2.conf

```
Alias /static/ /home/myproject/staticfiles/

<Directory /home/myproject/staticfiles>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

All my static files are present in `/home/myproject/static` and I would like to serve them from `/home/myproject/staticfiles`

Running `python manage.py collectstatic` seems to print the correct message

> You have requested to collect static files at the destination
>   location as specified in your settings:
>   /home/myproject/staticfiles

For test purposes I have a file `static/test1.css` which shows up on myproject.com/static/test1.css. However file `staticfiles/test2.css` does not show up on myproject.com/static/test2.css. This confirms that Apache is rendering the files form /static/ instead of /staticfiles/

Am I missing something basic here? I am on Django 1.7 Have been staring at this for a while now and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I was updating the wrong config file for apache.
I had `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/myproject.com.conf` and the settings in `myproject.com.conf` were taking precedence over `apache2.conf` settings. Should have realized that earlier. Yikes!